# A Wine Problem for Puzzlers

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, visual

> Simple Follow the instructions on the label.

[image]

In case you the image is too small, Given three bottles: 8, 5 and 3 liters capacity, divide 8 liters in half (4 + 4 liters) with the minimum number of wine transfers. Note that the 8-liter bottle is initially filled with 8 liters of wine and the other two bowls are empty. There is no extra wine anywhere, and this is not a trick question. It can be solved.

Comment: I made this from scratch using common variables for this puzzle. Unless someone is a mindreader, this is not a duplicate. There may be a similar puzzle with similar numbers, but as far as I know, questions don't get marked duplicate because it is "similar".

Comment: @Deusive, Ooooh I see why you marked duplicate. LOL they used the same data which would return same or close answer. Oh well, mine is a little different. I will get a little more random in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in

> 7 transfers

Method

> 1. Fill the 5-litre bottle from the 8-litre bottle 
>  2. Fill the 3-litre bottle from the 5-litre bottle 
>  3. Empty the contents of the 3-litre bottle into the 8-litre bottle 
>  4. Empty the 2 litres in the 5-litre bottle into the 3-litre bottle 
>  5. Fill the 5-litre bottle from the 8-litre bottle. 
>  6. Fill the 3-litre bottle from the 5-litre bottle. 
>  7. Empty the contents of the 3-litre bottle into the 8-litre bottle.

Table

> Step       8L bottle       5L bottle       3L bottle 
>    0                8                   0                  0 
>    1                3                   5                  0 
>    2                3                   2                  3 
>    3                6                   2                  0 
>    4                6                   0                  2 
>    5                1                   5                  2 
>    6                1                   4                  3 
>    7                4                   4                  0

Comment: oops... sniped by 1 min... +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Yes, it looked to be the same method. I think I've found a slightly improved version.

Answer (score 1):

```
Step   8L bottle   5L bottle   3L bottle 
 0         8           0           0
 1         5           0           3
 2         5           3           0
 3         2           3           3
 4         2           5           1
 5         7           0           1
 6         7           1           0
 7         4           1           3
 8         4           4           0
```